# Rotating panels with GeometricTransformation

Tags: graphics3d, geometry, geometric-transform

In the field of architecture, learning to manipulate geometry so comprehensively with *Mathematica* has been fun. However, I seem to have reached my limits with the following `GeometricTransformation` of panels generated with the following code:

```
poly=Module[{div=6,len=16000,list,sqx,sqy,h=Table[{1+c,2+c,9+c,8+c},{c,0,40}],listy,listx},
list=Flatten[Table[{x,y,z},{x,0,len,len/div},{y,0,len,len/div},{z,0,len,len/div}],2];
sqy=Select[list,#[[1]]==0&];
sqx=Select[list,#[[2]]==0&];
listy=Drop[Part[sqy,#] &/@ h,{7,40,7}];
listx=Drop[Part[sqx,#] &/@ h,{7,40,7}];
Polygon/@ Join[listx,listy]];
```

[image: panels]

What I'm trying to do next is to rotate each individual panel by some controllable degree, but instead the whole thing moves as one:

```
Graphics3D[GeometricTransformation[#, RotationMatrix[-Pi/8,{1,0,0}]] &/@ poly]
```

[image: rotate panel]

I've tried using `RegionBounds` to somehow create a vector axis to rotate each individual panel around, but seem to get stuck in 1) creating the vector and 2) feeding each panel's rotation vector back into `GeometricTransform`. Eventually I'd like to randomize the direction of the opening and generalize the function for any division of the surface but it's time to ask for help. Thanks.

**Update:** It occurred to me that I could include an image of the building to show the final geometry we are aiming for. (Here presented under a CC license credit:PeterBarr) [image: building]

**Update 18-03-18**

Taking the below suggestions as a starting point, I've decided to 1) angle the plane outward and 2) randomly select one of the 4 edges to use as an axis in one step. I've worked out the geometry of such an approach which needs to take into account which vertex of the plane is randomly selected to then assign the correct vector direction. I should be able to develop a list to feed into the `RotationTransform` however when trying to execute my RandomChoice function, only the geometry of the first polygon is used 10 times. Very strange. Any suggestions?

```
x1={{0,0,1},#[[1,1]]};x2={{1,0,0},#[[1,2]]};x3={{0,0,-1},#[[1,3]]};x4={{-1,0,0},#[[1,4]]};
RandomChoice[{v1,v2,v3,v4}] &/@ poly[[;;]]
```

**Final Update 18-03-21**

After a little reverse engineering I got exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help.

```
panel[f_]:=Module[{f1,f2,, \[Theta] = -Pi/5},
f1 =MakePolygons[Table[N[{x, 0, z}], {x, 0, f}, {z, 0, f}]];
f2=MakePolygons[Table[N[{0, y, z}], {y, 0, f}, {z, 0, f}]];
Table[Graphics3D[{spinPanel2[#, RandomInteger[{1, 4}], \[Theta]] &/@ f1,
spinPanel2[#, RandomInteger[{1, 4}], \[Theta]] &/@ f2}, 
ImageSize-> Small,Boxed->False,Lighting->"Neutral",ViewPoint->n],{n,{Front,{1,-2,2},{2,-3,2},{-5,1,2}}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You want to be able to rotate the two panels independently?

Comment: I want to try to control all the divided panels independently. I've updated the original question with more info and will try to run through the suggested solutions later tonight.

Comment: Wait... so are you envisioning $6\times 6\times 2$ rotation controls in your example, one for each panel?

Comment: I want to apply the same rotation to each individual panel instead of having the whole surface rotate as one. Then I will try to randomize the rotation. I'm having trouble finding the vector of each panel to rotate around. Tho @kglr's information was helpful and appricated.

Comment: "which needs to take into account which vertex of the plane is randomly selected " - why not pick edges instead of picking corners, just like what kglr and I are doing? The rotation going in a desired direction will now depend on whether the vertices are oriented clockwise or anticlockwise when facing you.

Comment: Good job on the last update. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me offer a toy for you to play with:

```
MakePolygons[vl_] /; ArrayQ[vl, 3] := 
    Flatten[Apply[Polygon[Join[Reverse[#1], #2]] &, 
                  Partition[vl, {2, 2}, {1, 1}], {2}]]

spinPanel[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ], α_, β_, γ_] := With[{cent = Mean[pts]}, 
    Polygon[AffineTransform[{RollPitchYawMatrix[{α, β, γ}], cent}]
            [TranslationTransform[-cent][pts]]]]

DynamicModule[{p = 6, q = 6, α1 = 0, β1 = 0, γ1 = 0, α2 = 0, β2 = 0, γ2 = 0},
              Panel[Row[{Column[{
                    Row[{"Width: ", Slider[Dynamic[p], {2, 10, 1}]}], 
                    Row[{"Height: ", Slider[Dynamic[q], {2, 10, 1}]}], 
                    Graphics3D[{Dynamic[spinPanel[#, α1, β1, γ1] & /@ 
                                MakePolygons[Table[N[{x, 0, z}],
                                                   {x, 0, p}, {z, 0, q}]], 
                                TrackedSymbols :> {p, q, α1, β1, γ1}], 
                                Dynamic[spinPanel[#, α2, β2, γ2] & /@ 
                                MakePolygons[Table[N[{0, y, z}],
                                                   {y, 0, p}, {z, 0, q}]], 
                                TrackedSymbols :> {p, q, α2, β2, γ2}]}, 
                               ImageSize -> Scaled[3/8]]}], Spacer[10], 
                    Grid[{{"", "Panel 1", "Panel 2"},
                          {"Pitch", Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[γ1]],
                                    Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[γ2]]},
                          {"Roll", Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[β1]],
                                   Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[β2]]},
                          {"Yaw", Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[α1]],
                                  Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[α2]]}}]}]]]
```

[image: rotatable panels]

---

Here's the version where the panels swivel by their hinges:

```
spinPanel2[Polygon[pts_?MatrixQ], k : (1 | 2 | 3 | 4), θ_] := 
    With[{axis = {pts[[k]], pts[[Mod[k + 1, 4, 1]]]}}, 
         Polygon[RotationTransform[θ, axis[[2]] - axis[[1]], axis[[1]]][pts]]]

DynamicModule[{p = 6, q = 6, k1 = 1, k2 = 1, θ1 = 0, θ2 = 0}, 
              Panel[Row[{Column[{Row[{"Width: ", Slider[Dynamic[p], {2, 10, 1}]}], 
                                 Row[{"Height: ", Slider[Dynamic[q], {2, 10, 1}]}], 
                                 Graphics3D[{Dynamic[spinPanel2[#, k1, θ1] & /@ 
                                             MakePolygons[Table[N[{x, 0, z}],
                                                                {x, 0, p}, {z, 0, q}]], 
                                             TrackedSymbols :> {p, q, k1, θ1}], 
                                             Dynamic[spinPanel2[#, k2, -θ2] & /@ 
                                             MakePolygons[Table[N[{0, y, z}],
                                                                {y, 0, p}, {z, 0, q}]], 
                                             TrackedSymbols :> {p, q, k2, θ2}]}, 
                                            ImageSize -> Scaled[3/8], 
                                            PlotRange -> {{-1, p}, {-1, p}, {0, q}}]}],
                         Spacer[10], 
                         Grid[{{"Panel 1", "Panel 2"},
                               {SetterBar[Dynamic[k1],
                                {4 -> "Top", 2 -> "Bottom", 1 -> "Left", 3 -> "Right"}], 
                                SetterBar[Dynamic[k2],
                                {4 -> "Top", 2 -> "Bottom", 3 -> "Left", 1 -> "Right"}]},
                               {Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[θ1]], 
                                Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic[θ2]]}}]}]]]
```

[image: hinged panels]

Using the same idea, plus a little randomization:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[1464]; (* for reproducibility *)
            With[{p = 6, q = 6},
                 Module[{f1, f2},
                        f1 = MakePolygons[Table[N[{x, 0, z}], {x, 0, p}, {z, 0, q}]];
                        f2 = MakePolygons[Table[N[{0, y, z}], {y, 0, p}, {z, 0, q}]];
                        Graphics3D[{{FaceForm[],
                                     EdgeForm[Directive[GrayLevel[2/3],
                                                        AbsoluteThickness[4]]],
                                     f1, f2},
                                    {EdgeForm[GrayLevel[3/4]],
                                     {FaceForm[Opacity[3/4,
                                               ColorData["Legacy", "AliceBlue"]], Gray], 
                                      spinPanel2[#, RandomInteger[{1, 4}],
                                                 RandomReal[π/4]] & /@ f1},
                                     {FaceForm[Gray, 
                                               Opacity[3/4,
                                               ColorData["Legacy", "AliceBlue"]]],
                                      spinPanel2[#, RandomInteger[{1, 4}],
                                                 -RandomReal[π/4]] & /@ f2}}},
                                   Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]]]
```

[image: randomly opened panels]

Comment: This is pretty epic! I can barely read it considering my coding level. Making the polygons by arrays is straightforward, but I've never even heard of functions like ``RollPitchYawMatrix``. Nicely done. I can at least appricate it.

Comment: Now that I look at it, my solution pivots the panels around their centers (that's what the `cent = Mean[pts]` in `spinPanel[]` was for), but you seem to want to be able to rotate around the four possible sides. I'll edit this solution later, but it should be a straightforward (albeit tedious) conversion.

Answer (score 8):

```
t1 = -Pi/8; v1 = {1, 0, 0};
t2 = -Pi/4; v2 = {0, 1, 0};
Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[#, RotationMatrix[t1, v1]] & /@ poly[[;; 36]], 
  GeometricTransformation[#, RotationMatrix[t2, v2]] & /@  poly[[37 ;;]]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Rotate each polygon independently:

```
Graphics3D[{Hue[RandomReal[]], GeometricTransformation[#, 
     RotationMatrix[RandomReal[{-Pi/6, Pi/6}], 
      Mean@RandomChoice[Partition[#[[1]], 2, 1, 1]]]]} & /@ poly, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

**Update:** Swiveling each polygon around randomly selected side using `RotationTransform`:

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5, Yellow], poly, 
 {Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
  GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[RandomReal[{-Pi/6, Pi/6}], 
  RandomChoice[{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], RandomChoice[#[[1, {2, 4}]]]]]}&/@ poly[[;; 36]], 
 {Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
  GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[RandomReal[{-Pi/6, Pi/6}], 
  RandomChoice[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}], RandomChoice[#[[1, {2, 4}]]]]]}&/@ poly[[37 ;;]]},
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

or, more compactly,

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5, Yellow], poly,
  {Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
     GeometricTransformation[#, RotationTransform[RandomReal[{-Pi/6, Pi/6}], 
       RandomChoice[{If[Total@#[[1, All, 2]] == 0, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}], {0, 0, 1}}], 
       RandomChoice[#[[1, {2, 4}]]]]]} & /@ poly}, 
 Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Another view:

[image]

You can also use post-processing

```
Show[Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], Opacity[.5, Yellow], poly}], 
 Graphics3D[poly] /. Polygon[x_] :> {EdgeForm[Gray], Hue[RandomReal[]], 
    GeometricTransformation[Polygon[x], RotationTransform[RandomReal[{-Pi/6, Pi/6}], 
      RandomChoice[{If[Total@x[[All, 2]] == 0, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}], {0, 0, 1}}], 
      RandomChoice[x[[{1, 4}]]]]]}, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

to get the same result.

Using `RandomChoice[{0, Pi/2, Pi, 4/3 Pi, 2 Pi}]` instead of  `RandomReal[{-Pi/6, Pi/6}]` we get

[image]

Change `RandomChoice[#[[1, {1, 4}]]]` to `Mean[#[[1]]]` to to swivel around the center (`Yellow` is replaced with `Gray` below):

[image]

Comment: Trying this solution tonight I've improved but still missing something. What does the 4th option do in ``Partition[#[[1]], 2, 1, 1]``? And what if I only wanted 4 random options? One up, down and each side?

Comment: @BBirdsell,  re `Partition`, try `Partition[{a,b,c}, 2,1]` vs `Partition[{a,b,c},2,1,1]`.  Re the "4 random options": if  you want to use one of the 4 sides as the hinge, using `RotationTransform` may be more convenient as its three-argument form allows specification of an anchor. I will post an update when i get a chance.

Comment: It's taken a while to reverse engineer your advanced use of ``Part`` to understand what's being selected. (MMA is pretty powerful in its abstraction). I'm stumbling now to have any 1 of the 4 polygon edges selected as the axis of rotation randomly, then a apply a contact rotation to that randomly selected edge. Progress is being made.